# Lattice Reduction

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, mathematical-lattices

I have two matrices A and B with same number of rows. Consider a Lattice generated by the rows of B. I want to reduce B and during the reduction change A accordingly. That is if i-th row and j-th row of B interchanges, need to sweep i-th row and j-th row of A also, similarly other elementary row operations. How can I do these?

Also is there very simple C or C++-implementation of the [LLL algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LLLAlgorithm.html)?

Comment: Are you using C, or C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://www.sagemath.org/download-source.html) is the source code to sage, a FOSS symbolic math program. It has an implementation of the triple-L that you could use provided you're willing to GPL the code once it's done. [This](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.stehle/#software) is another standalone implementation.

Comment: I feel obligated to add that the notion of a "simple" implementation of the triple-L is somewhat silly, as it is a particularly complicated algorithm.